# problems with a portscanner in python

Tags: python, security

**There's a cybersecurity course, and one of the exercises is to make a port scanner. I think mine works but still the instant feedback doesn't give me the points. Here's the exercise:**

```
import sys
import socket


def get_accessible_ports(address, min_port, max_port):
    found_ports = []

    # write code here

    return found_ports


def main(argv):
    address = sys.argv[1]
    min_port = int(sys.argv[2])
    max_port = int(sys.argv[3])
    ports = get_accessible_ports(address, min_port, max_port)
    for p in ports:
        print(p)

# This makes sure the main function is not called immediatedly
# when TMC imports this module
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print('usage: python %s address min_port max_port' % sys.argv[0])
    else:
        main(sys.argv)
```

For this assignment, you should write the code needed for the method get_accessible_ports to scan the given range of ports. The method should scan the ports at a given address, and then return the list of ports that have a service listening for them.

Note that the test server will not submit any data; you shouldn't try to receive any data.

**And here's my code:**

```
import sys
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


def get_accessible_ports(address, min_port, max_port):
    found_ports = []
    

    while min_port <= max_port:
        try:
            s.connect(address, min_port)
                                
        except:
            
            min_port += 1
            continue
        else:
            
            found_ports.append(min_port)
            min_port += 1
            continue
           

    return found_ports


def main(argv):
    address = sys.argv[1]
    min_port = int(sys.argv[2])
    max_port = int(sys.argv[3])
    ports = get_accessible_ports(address, min_port, max_port)
    for p in ports:
        print(p)

# This makes sure the main function is not called immediatedly
# when TMC imports this module
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print('usage: python %s address min_port max_port' % sys.argv[0])
    else:
        main(sys.argv)
```

**Here's the feedback of the exercise:**
Testing: part1-01.portscanner
Failed: test.test_portscanner.PortScanner.test_scan
Lists differ: [] != [25964]

Second list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
25964

- []

- [25964] : port scanner did not find the correct port

Failed: test.test_portscanner.PortScanner.test_single
Lists differ: [] != [24600]

Second list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
24600

- []

- [24600] : port scanner did not test port when called with min_port = max_port

Test results: 0/2 tests passed
0%[░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░]

**Any idea on what is going on?? Help will be strongly appreciated, thanks**

Answer (score 1):

You're silenced all possible exceptions instead of specific ones (related to a connection problems) without any output:

```
try:
   ...
except:
    ...
```

That's why you missed the problem with address: socket.connect() accepting a tuple of `(host, port)`. It's a **single** argument, not two.

```py
s.connect(address, min_port)
# ->
s.connect((address, min_port))
```

Beside of that, please try to initialize socket inside of your function, don't use one socket to test all the ports:

```py
def fn(addr, min_port, max_port):
  
    while min_port <= max_port:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            try:
                s.connect((addr, min_port))
            except <SOME SPECIFIC EXCEPTION THAT MEANS THE PORT IS UNREACHABLE>:
                pass
            except Exception:
                print('SOMETHING REALLY BAD HAPPENED!')
                print('BUT NOW AT LEAST YOU CAN SEE IT HAPPENED:)')
                raise
            else:
                yield min_port
            finally:
                min_port += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it works :). Btw, what is the difference between initializing the socket at the top of the method and initializing it inside the loop? I understand that it would generate a new socket for each try(s.connect((addr, min_port))), but what does this exactly imply?

Comment: The number of connections that can be made from a single socket is quite limited. If you don't disconnect socket from the ports you've already checked, you may hit the limit. The simple way to ensure that all set is just to use the new socket each time, and use it in a context manager (`with` statement) to let python maintain resources for you.